# Register Listener in constructor of subclass

Tags: java, android

I need to register a `Listener` in my subclass on an inherited `final` field (`mCursorLoader`). I need to do this in the `constructor` of my subclass. **Preferably without changing the fields to `non-final` or doing any `unRegistering` in the subclass.**

The problem is that my parent class is registering the `Listener` from its implementation in its constructor. And i need a way to either prevent it from registering that `Listener` and then register the subclasses `Listener` or unRegister the parent classes `Listener` and then register the subclasses `Listener`.

Having a hard time explaining, so if it needs more clarification, please let me know.

```
public abstract class A<T> extends AsyncTaskLoader<List<T>> {

        protected final Listener mListener = new Listener();
        protected final CursorLoader mCursorLoader;
        protected final String mId;

        public A(Context context, String mId) {

                super(context);
                this.mCursorLoader = new CursorLoader(context);
                this.mCursorLoader.registerListener(0, mListener);
                this.mId = mId;

        }

        public class Listener implements OnLoadCompleteListener<Cursor> {

                public void onLoadComplete(final Loader<Cursor> loader, final Cursor cursor) {

                }
        }
}

public abstract class B<T> extends A<T> {

        protected B(Context context, String mId) {

                super(context, mId);

        }

        public class Listener implements OnLoadCompleteListener<Cursor> {

                public void onLoadComplete(final Loader<Cursor> loader, final Cursor cursor) {

                }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a constructor to your base class (or modify the existing one) that takes a listener as argument, and registers this listener instead of the base class listener:

```
protected A(Context context, String mId, OnLoadCompleteListener<Cursor> listener) {
    super(context);
    this.mCursorLoader = new CursorLoader(context);
    this.mCursorLoader.registerListener(0, listener);
    this.mId = mId;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but i figured out what i am going to do. It is very similar to what you suggested. I am just going to delete the question, as this is very localized. Thanks